Which CPU metric does cloudrun use to decide if a multiple containers service should a autoscale?
I'm looking to understand how Cloud Run autoscales services with multiple containers.
Does it use the run.googleapis.com/container/cpu/utilizations metrics which seems to be an aggregate of both containers or the run.googleapis.com/container/cpu/usage which is defined for multi containers?
My setup has a small metric collector which uses very little cpu vs my application. I want the autoscaling to kick in when my application is struggling
I have had a read through the docs but there is no mention of which metrics is used.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

When you hit 60% on run.googleapis.com/container/cpu/utilizations, it autoscales. Even past max instance count sometimes :)
Good links here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling and here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency
